# exporting data frame from R to excel

Tags: r, export-to-excel

I have a large data frame(df). I want to export it as an excel file. I am using "WriteXLS" function from "WriteXLS" library. Everything is fine except for some non English characters. For "İ", "ı" and for some other characters a strange object(which is "�") is printed in the excel sheet. I guess it is an ecoding issue. The used code is:

```
WriteXLS("df", "C:/Users/ozgur/Desktop/df.xlsx",Encoding = "UTF-8", col.names = TRUE,perl = "perl")
```

The base exporting function

```
write.table(df, "C:/Users/ozgur/Desktop/df.txt", sep="\t",col.names=TURE)
```

does not work well. It does not convert data types as in R.

How can I overcome this problem. I will be very glad for any help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is is because you are saying `df.txt` and not `df.csv` in your file extension.

Comment: One option would be to try either **XLConnect** or **xlsx** to see if they handle the encoding a little better.

Comment: @NealC , write.table does not work well even with df.csv. Formats of columns does not recognised. Some numbers are recognised as date, some are recognised as character.

Comment: Try adding `sep=","` into the function. I normally use XLConnect or xlsx anyways. I'd also suggest trying `write.csv` although this isn't really a Excel file. Use a package.

Comment: Thanks a lot. library(xlsx)
write.xlsx(x = df, file = "C:/Users/ozgur/Desktop/df.xlsx",
           sheetName = "TestSheet", row.names = FALSE) worked very well

Comment: If you click "answer" the, we can conclude. Thak a lot.